# Proving Triangle Inequality for Specific Metric

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, inequality, metric-spaces

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space, $x \in X$, and $A \subseteq X$ nonempty. Define
$d(x, A) = \inf\{d(x, a) | a \in A\}$.

If $y \in X$ and $y \neq x$, show that $d(x, A) \leq d(x, y) + d(y, A)$.

**My work so far**: Let $\epsilon_x = \inf\{d(x, a) | a \in A\}$ and let $\epsilon_y = \inf\{d(y, a) | a \in A\}$. Then, $\exists \delta \geq 0$ such that $\epsilon_x + \delta = d(x,a)$ for some $a\in A$ and $\epsilon_y+\delta ' = d(y,a)$. Since $(X,d)$ is a metric space, we have that $d(x,a)\leq d(x,y)+d(y,a)$. But that only gives us  $ \epsilon_x +\delta\leq d(x,y) + \epsilon_y +\delta '$. My hope was to somehow be able to cancel the $\delta$'s and substitute back in to find the desired inequality, but that doesn't seem to be possible. Is this approach doable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are not correctly using the properties of the infimum. If
$\epsilon_y = \inf\{d(y, a) | a \in A\}$ then for **all** $\delta > 0$
there is an $a_0 \in A$ such that $d(y, a_0) < \epsilon_y + \delta$.

Then
$$
\epsilon_x = \inf\{d(x, a) | a \in A\} \le d(x, a_0)
 \le d(x,y) + d(y, a_0) < d(x, y) + \epsilon_y + \delta \, .
$$

Now use that $\delta > 0$ can be arbitrarily small.

Answer (score 0):

There is a an easier proof for this and also the function $f(x)=d(x,A):X \to [0,+\infty)$ is Lipschitz continuous.

> Let $x,y \in X$  then for all $a \in A$:

Note that $\inf_{a \in A}d(x,y)=d(x,y)$

> $$d(x,a) \leq d(x,y)+d(y,a) \Rightarrow \inf_{a \in A}d(x,a)$$ $$\leq d(x,y)+\inf_{a \in A}d(y,a) \Rightarrow d(x,A)-d(y,A) \leq d(x,y)$$(1)

(This proved your statement)

> Now for all $a \in A$ $$d(y,a) \leq d(x,a)+d(x,y)$$
>
> So following the previous argument by taking infimum to both  sides of the inequality we prove that $$d(y,A)-d(x,A) \leq d(x,y)$$(2)

Combining $(1),(2)$  we have that $$|d(x,A)-d(y,A)| \leq d(x,y)$$

So we proved also a stronger statement along with the original one.